# Wireguard Tunnel all Internet traffic but have access to local printer

Tags: wireguard

This AllowedIps: 0.0.0.0/0 setting routes all traffic thru Wireguard even LAN, which makes printing impossible.

How can I exclude printing from this, so I can print using my local wireless printer but still route all Internet traffic thru Wireguard VPN?

Windows client

Wireguard server is on VPS

Answer (score 2):

On your Windows machine, edit the tunnel in the WireGuard client, and un-check the **Block untunneled traffic (kill-switch)** checkbox (at the bottom of the **Edit tunnel** dialog box). When checked, this setting effectively prevents Windows from using the other routes in its routing table.

If that alone doesn't fix it, you may also need to add a static route specifically for your printer. Try running `route print` in a command prompt on your Windows machine -- this will display your existing route table. If a route to your printer (or to the subnet your printer is on) is not listed, try adding one manually by running `route add <printer ip address> <router ip address>` in the command prompt -- for example, run `route add 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1` if `192.168.1.2` is your printer's address, and `192.168.1.1` is your local router's ip address.

If adding a static route fixes it, you can add the route permanently (ie persisting after restarts etc) by adding the `-p` flag (eg `route -p add 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2`); or later delete the route by running `route delete <printer ip address>` (eg `route delete 192.168.1.2`).

Comment: I'd like to point out, the `Block untunneled traffic (kill-switch)` only appears if your (on client machine) peer `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 0):

In my experimentation, I'd recommend keeping `AllowedIPs` intact as `0.0.0.0/0`. Instead, take advantage of the `PostUp` and `PreDown` steps in your wireguard config.

If you're downloading your killswitch configs from Mullvad, these steps are already included. All you need to do is add your local network to the `iptables` exclusion.

So the following config from Mullvad:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ###################################
Address = ##.##.##.##/32,####:####:####:####::3:5d1f/128
DNS = ##.##.##.##
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT

[Peer]
PublicKey = ###############################
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = ##.##.##.##:####
```

Turns into the following, where I've excluded my local network `10.0.0.1/24`, and to improve readability, split the concatenated `PostUp` and `PreDown` steps into two steps each:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ###################################
Address = ##.##.##.##/32,####:####:####:####::3:5d1f/128
DNS = ##.##.##.##
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL ! -d 10.0.0.1/24 -j REJECT
PostUp = ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL ! -d 10.0.0.1/24 -j REJECT
PreDown = ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT

[Peer]
PublicKey = ###############################
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = ##.##.##.##:####
```

You can exclude additional ipv4 IPs by adding additional `! -d ##.##.##.##/##` before the line's `-j REJECT`. The same can be done for ipv6 in the `ip6tables` commands.

Here's a quick python script I threw together to update all of my configs with my ipv4 exclusion. It'll preserve existing exclusions, split concatenated `PostUp` and `PreDown` commands, and save the original to `.old`. Sample usage: `python3 excludeIpv4.py 10.0.0.1/24`:

```python
# excludeIpv4.py
import os
import sys

path = "/path/to/your/configs" # << change this
configFileEnding = '.conf'

os.chdir(path)

excludeIpv4 = sys.argv[1]

# will add ip exclusion to PostUp and PreDown steps
# will split concatenated PostUp and PreDown steps
# will preserve existing IP exclusions
def modifyFile(filePath):
    dnsIdx = -1
    newFileContents = []
    existingExclusion = "! --dst-type LOCAL"
    newExclusion = f"! --dst-type LOCAL ! -d {excludeIpv4}"
    renamedFileName = filePath + ".old"

    with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
        fileContents = f.read().split("\n")
        for line in fileContents:
            if line.startswith("#"):
                continue

            # modify PostUp
            if line.startswith("PostUp"):
                newLines = line.split(" && ")
                for newLine in newLines:
                    if not newLine.startswith("PostUp"):
                        newLine = "PostUp = " + newLine
                    if newLine.find("iptables") > -1:
                        newLine = newLine.replace(existingExclusion, newExclusion)
                    newFileContents.append(newLine)
            
            # modify PreDown
            elif line.startswith("PreDown"):
                newLines = line.split(" && ")
                for newLine in newLines:
                    if not newLine.startswith("PreDown"):
                        newLine = "PreDown = " + newLine
                    if newLine.find("iptables") > -1:
                        newLine = newLine.replace(existingExclusion, newExclusion)
                    newFileContents.append(newLine)
            
            else:
                newFileContents.append(line)

        # save original file to new file
        with open(renamedFileName, 'w') as f:
            f.write("\n".join(fileContents))

    
    # write new content to new file
    with open(filePath, 'w') as f:
        f.write("\n".join(newFileContents))

    return renamedFileName, filePath


print(f"Adding IPv4 exclusion of '{excludeIpv4}' to '{configFileEnding}' files in '{path}'...\n")
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(configFileEnding):
        filePath = os.path.join(path, file)
        print(f"Modifying {filePath}...")
        renamed, new = modifyFile(filePath)
        print(f"File updated. Saved original to {renamed}\n")
```